# Enum how to return enum's string content inside enum object

Tags: java, enums

Example

```
public enum STUFF
{
    THING("Ok"), STUFF("Sweet"), PEOPLE("umm"), CAR("Vrrm");

    String contents;

    STUFF(String x)
    {
       contents = x;
    }

    public String getContents()
    {
        return ??
    }

}
```

Desired result:

```
System.out.print(STUFF.CAR.getContents());
//Vrrm
```

Comment: ahh... I guess it really was that simple @PrinceJohnWesley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment in the constructor is wrong.

```
x = contents;
```

should be: -

```
contents = x;
```

And the return value in `getContents()` should be: -

```
public String getContents()
{
    return contents;
}
```

Comment: @stackoverflow.. It's ok. I thought that was intentional. But that should get you what you want. :)

Answer (score 4):

You should review the planets example at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

```
public enum STUFF
{
    THING("Ok"), STUFF("Sweet"), PEOPLE("umm"), CAR("Vrrm");

    private final String contents;

    STUFF(String x)
    {
        contents = x;
    }

    public String getContents()
    {
        return contents;
    }
 }
```

Comment: The only dumb thing you could have done was to have not asked your question. No shame in learning!